# about cauchy sequences' epsilons

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

When showing a sequence is cauchy, we are trying show validity of an inequality whose RHS is epsilon. I noticed that authors try to avoid making RHS epsilon multiplied by a constant apart from 1. For example, when showing  sum of two cauchy sequences is also cauchy, they set their epsilons as epsilon/2 at the beginning and when you add them you have epsilon. But why do we bother? What is wrong with obtaining 2epsilon at RHS?

Comment: Nothing wrong just because it looks better

Comment: You presumably have a definition of a Cauchy sequence saying something like $\forall \epsilon >0: \exists N: \forall n>N: \forall m>N: |x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$.  So to show your new sequence (here the sum of the two sequences) is Cauchy, you want to end up with $\epsilon$ on the right hand side